Remove BOM from UTF 8 using cmd
I need to remove BOM using cmd file from MyFile.txt. The file is located here.
| Out-File -encoding utf8 '%CD%\MyFile.txt'

I need it to be removed using only one cmd, that is, in the next lines. I need it to be backwards compatible to Windows 7. If I needed it for myself only I would just use -encoding default, but its not backwards compatible even to win 10. Just one file. There were many different questions about BOM on different situations, my issue is I need to use one .cmd, I already have utf8 with BOM and I need it without BOM. Please help me.
I was trying to use powershell but the issue is powershell syntax is not really compatible to cmd? It just says about unrecognised syntax everytime I tried anything from the very popular theme like this Using PowerShell to write a file in UTF-8 without the BOM.

As an aside: -Encoding Default will result in an ANSI-encoded file in Windows PowerShell, not UTF-8 (By contrast, in PowerShell (Core) 7, -Encoding Default does result in a BOM-less UTF-8 file, but the argument is redundant there, given that BOM-less UTF-8 is the (consistent) default.)

PowerShell is indeed your best bet, and while you cannot directly use PowerShell commands from cmd.exe / a batch file, you can pass them to powershell.exe, the Windows PowerShell CLI (the solutions below also work on the no longer supported Windows 7 edition of Windows, as requested).
Preface:

If your file is created with Windows PowerShell code, as seems to be the case, you can avoid your problem altogether, by writing a BOM-less UTF-8 file to begin with, using one of the workarounds summarized in this answer in lieu of Out-File -Encoding utf8

In PowerShell (Core) 7, the problem wouldn't even arise, because there all cmdlets consistently default to BOM-less UTF-8; however, this - install-on-demand - PowerShell edition isn't supported on Windows 7.


The solutions below address your question as asked:

How to remove a UTF-8 BOM after the fact, from an existing file, relying on Windows PowerShell, the legacy Windows-only edition of PowerShell whose latest and last version is 5.1, which ships with Windows since Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2.[1]

Additionally, the use case of transcoding the input file, i.e. saving it with a different character encoding is addressed.




Here's a sample batch file that demonstrates a solution, i.e. it converts a UTF-8 file with BOM to a BOM-less one in-place (best to make a backup copy first):
@echo off & setlocal

:: Specify the input file, assumed to be a UTF-8 file *with-BOM*.
set "targetFile=%CD%\MyFile.txt"

:: Call Windows PowerShell in order to 
:: convert the file to a *BOM-less** UTF-8 file.
powershell -noprofile -c $null = New-Item $env:targetFile -Force -Value (Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath $env:targetFile)

Note: The -c (-Command) and -noprofile CLI parameters aren't strictly necessary, but are included for conceptual clarity and to avoid unnecessary processing of profile files.
Alternatively, using the [IO.File]::WriteAllText() .NET API:
:: ...

powershell -noprofile -c [IO.File]::WriteAllText((Convert-Path -LiteralPath $env:targetFile), (Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath $env:targetFile))

Note:

The PowerShell code takes advantage of the fact that New-Item, when given a -Value argument, creates a BOM-less UTF-8 file, even in Windows PowerShell (the legacy, ships-with-Windows, Windows-only edition of PowerShell whose latest and last version is 5.1); ditto for [IO.File]::WriteAllText() - see this answer for details; Get-Content automatically recognizes a UTF-8 file with BOM as such (and faithfully reads it into a .NET string on which New-Item then operates).

Note: The above uses a text-based approach; strictly speaking, if you know your input files to always be a UTF-8 encoded, to always have a BOM, and you want to convert them to BOM-less UTF-8, you can alternatively use byte processing, namely by simply rewriting the file with the first 3 bytes (which comprise the BOM) omitted. However, a text-based approach, while more memory-intensive, offers more flexibility, especially when transcoding is needed, as discussed later:

js2010's answer shows a conceptually straightforward way to remove the first 3 bytes; however, since each byte from the input file is sent individually through the pipeline, processing is quite slow; on the flip side, this approach keeps memory consumption low.

A faster alternative - which reads all bytes into memory first - is the following (a memory-friendly alternative is possible, but requires more work; if you were to call PowerShell (Core) 7 instead, via pwsh.exe, you'd have to replace -Encoding Byte with -AsByteStream):
:: IMPORTANT: If the input file is *not* a UTF-8 file
::            with a BOM, the following will *corrupt it*.
powershell -noprofile -c [IO.File]::WriteAllBytes((Convert-Path -LiteralPath $env:targetFile), [Linq.Enumerable]::Skip((Get-Content -Raw -Encoding Byte -LiteralPath $env:targetFile), 3))




If, judging by your later comments, you're actually trying to transcode your file, i.e. to switch to a different character encoding, you can use Set-Content with an -Encoding argument; however, in Windows PowerShell you're limited to a fixed number of Unicode encodings plus only the active OEM and ANSI code pages, which you can target with -Encoding Oem and -Encoding Default, respectively, and Get-Content and Set-Content even default to the latter.

Thus, if you want to transcode your file to a (by definition BOM-less) file encoded using the Windows-1251 code page (Cyrillic), for instance:

The following only works in Windows PowerShell if that code page is also the system's active ANSI code page (verify with [Text.Encoding]::Default.WebName; when calling from a batch file, you can change to Windows-1251 with chcp 1251 first, but note that, unless you explicitly restore the previous code page afterwards, this will remain in effect for the remainder of the batch file and, if your batch file was started from an interactive cmd.exe session, for the remainder of the latter); -Encoding Default, which selects the system's active ANSI code page, is implied with Set-Content and therefore omitted below (you would need it with Out-File, however, though use of this cmdlet isn't necessary for writing text):
 :: Transcode the file to Windows-1251, 
 :: assuming the latter is the active ANSI code page. 
 :: Note: `-Encoding Default` is implied for Set-Content in Windows PowerShell
 powershell -noprofile -c Set-Content -NoNewLine -LiteralPath $env:targetFile -Value (Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath $env:targetFile)


Otherwise, you need to use .NET APIs directly, so you can use [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1251) to obtain the Windows-1251 encoding irrespective of the system's active ANSI code page and pass it to [IO.File]::WriteAllText():[2]
 :: Transcode the file to Windows-1251, irrespective
 :: of what the active ANSI code page is.
 powershell -noprofile -c [IO.File]::WriteAllText((Convert-Path -LiteralPath $env:targetFile), (Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath $env:targetFile), [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1251))


Note that this approach can be adapted to perform transcoding from any supported input encoding to any supported output encoding. While Get-Content's -Encoding parameter is subject to the same limitation as Set-Content's, you can replace Get-Content with a call to [IO.File]::ReadAllText(), to which you can similarly pass any [Text.Encoding] instance.


Note that this transcoding is potentially lossy, because not all Unicode characters can be represented in a fixed, single-byte encoding such as Windows-1251, given that only 256 characters can be represented.





Caveat: By reading the entire file into memory first, with Get-Content -Raw, and rewriting it in full, in place - with BOM-less UTF-8 encoding - there is a hypothetical risk of data loss, however unlikely: if rewriting the file's content gets interrupted, say due to a power outage, data loss may occur.

To eliminate this risk, you'd have to write to a temporary file first, and then, once the temporary file was successfully written, replace the original file with it.

Similarly, you'd need a temporary file if the input file is too large to fit into memory as a whole (which is not typical for text files); in that case, you can combine [IO.File]::ReadLines() with [IO.File]::WriteAllLines() to read and write line by line.





The following solution addresses these problems:

It uses a temporary file and reads and writes lines one at a time.

It is therefore a more robust solution that is memory-friendly, albeit at the expense of implementation complexity and speed (though the latter typically won't matter)



@echo off & setlocal

set "targetFile=%CD%\MyFile.txt"

powershell -noprofile -c $ErrorActionPreference='Stop'; $tempFile=New-TemporaryFile; $inFile=Convert-Path -LiteralPath $env:targetFile; [IO.File]::WriteAllLines($tempFile, [IO.File]::ReadLines($inFile)); $tempFile ^| Move-Item -Force -Destination $inFile

Note:

Passing multiple statements to powershell.exe gets unwieldy, as you must either pass them all on a single line or use cmd.exe's line-continuations; here's a readable reformulation that you could use if you placed the code in a PowerShell script file (*.ps1) and then called powershell -noprofile -file yourScript.ps1 (though if you took that approach, it'd be worth generalizing the code to accept the input file path as an argument):
# PowerShell code for use in a *.ps1 script file.
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$tempFile = New-TemporaryFile
$inFile = Convert-Path -LiteralPath $env:targetFile
[IO.File]::WriteAllLines(
  $tempFile,
  [IO.File]::ReadLines($inFile)
)
$tempFile | Move-Item -Force -Destination $inFile


Note that while the use of [IO.File]::WriteAllLines() and [IO.File]::ReadLines() without specifying a character encoding may look like a no-op in terms of BOM removal, it does work as intended: .NET recognizes a UTF-8 file with BOM on reading, and, on writing,  writes a UTF-8 file without BOM by default.

If you're looking to transcode your file, as discussed above, you can pass a [System.Text.Encoding] instance to the third parameter of [IO.File]::WriteAllLines(), which gives you full access to all encodings supported by .NET; e.g., for Windows-1251:
 # PowerShell code for use in a *.ps1 script file.
 $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
 $tempFile = New-TemporaryFile
 $inFile = Convert-Path -LiteralPath $env:targetFile
 # Note the [Text.Encoding] argument.
 [IO.File]::WriteAllLines(
   $tempFile,
   [IO.File]::ReadLines($inFile),
   [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1251)
 )
 $tempFile | Move-Item -Force -Destination $inFile


Similarly, you can optionally pass a [Text.Encoding] instance to the [IO.File]::ReadLines() method, in case you also need to specify the input encoding explicitly (which would apply to non-Unicode files and UTF-7 files).





[1] These versions originally shipped with v2 of Windows PowerShell, though upgrades to later versions were possible. The solutions in this answer work even in v2.
Calling Windows PowerShell from a batch file via powershell.exe) is the only way to solve your problem with built-in features; cmd.exe's built-in features are far less powerful and offer no solution, and Windows doesn't ship with a file-transcoding utility (whereas Unix-like platforms come with the iconv utility.
[2] Note that in PowerShell (Core) 7 you wouldn't need to resort to .NET APIs, because the -Encoding parameter there now accepts any [Text.Encoding] instance, either directly, or by name (e.g., -Encoding Windows-1251) or by code-page number (e.g., -Encoding 1251); applied to your scenario:
pwsh -noprofile -c Set-Content -Encoding 1251 -NoNewLine -LiteralPath $env:targetFile -Value (Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath $env:targetFile)

That's not CMD, it's just calling PS. Why not calling PHP or straight an EXE all along?

@AmigoJack: cmd.exe is a shell. Shells (and their script (batch) files), in addition to having their built in commands, are designed to call external programs, such as powershell.exe, which comes with Windows - unlike PHP or any file-transcoding utilities. In other words: this solution improves on your suggestion.

It still misses the requirement of the Q. And no: PS doesn't come with every Windows version or may be unavailable or its .NET dependency might be unavailable. Hence this A is not a CMD solution - it's a PS only solution. My comment question wanted to imply how little this A has to do with CMD.

@AmigoJack, no, it doesn't miss the requirement - nothing in the question says that only built-in cmd.exe commands must be used (which would make the problem all but impossible to solve). The Wikipedia article you link to directly contradicts your claim: "is bundled with all currently supported Windows versions".

Ugh, this is ridiculous - now you're making a new requirement nobody asked for ("supported" version). What if one needs a solution for an older version? What if there's an actual need to use CMD and EXEs that ship with older Windows versions? As per "supported" you could mention which PS version is needed.

I wrote in my .cmd
@echo off & setlocal
... here a lot of different code for elevation ...
powershell -Command "(gc '%CD%\MyFile.txt') "^
"-replace '^DataDirectory.*$', ('DataDirectory "%CD%\data"' -replace '\','\') "^
"| Out-File -encoding utf8 '%CD%\MyFile.txt'"
set "targetFile=%CD%\MyFile.txt"
powershell -noprofile -c New-Item $env:targetFile -Force -Value (Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath $env:targetFile)
Unfortunately it didn't do anything to MyFile.txt and I still got utf8-BOM. What am I missing?

@AmigoJack I need it to work at least on win 10 or even on win 7, but for now I can't make it work even on Win 11. This program isn't UTF8-BOM compatible. If I needed it only on win 11 and only for me I would just write | Out-File -encoding default '%CD%\MyFile.txt'. And I already used powershell it is win 7 compatible, the main issue is I need it to work through .cmd script in the folder which should properly modify '%CD%\MyFile.txt'. I am not a programmer by specialisation but I really need it for myself and for the people which relies on me.

"it didn't do anything" - so your file isn't even modified (changed file time)? Since the PS code nowhere does error checking it could fail for all reasons (missing write/move access. Or is the file actually modified, but just has the same content as before? Name the target program @VerityFreedom, preferably in your Q. And remove that ugly comment which just repeats code from the A.

When I wrote       "| Out-File -encoding utf8 '%CD%\MyFile.txt'"
setlocal
set "targetFile=%CD%\MyFile.txt"
powershell -noprofile -c $ErrorActionPreference='Stop'; $tempFile=New-TemporaryFile; $inFile=Convert-Path -LiteralPath $env:targetFile; [IO.File]::WriteAllLines($tempFile, [IO.File]::ReadLines($inFile)); $tempFile ^| Move-Item -Force -Destination $inFile
It just crashed

@AmigoJack It is firstly modified by powershell replace and encoded in utf8 (already done and win 7 compatible), then I need to encode it again in utf8NoBom and create a service, but the thing that was provided here didn't do anything at all, I got the usual utf8 with BOM. I need to convert relative to absolute path and it being compatible to Cyrillic and for this I need utf8NoBom. I would provide the full code for you to understand what am I trying to do but I can't because replies dont even support dividing by lines, so it looks "ugly" for you.

@AmigoJack, I forgot to mention that it is also bundled with Windows 7, which the question mentions as a requirement, so these solutions work just fine in Windows 7 and above. To summarize: the solutions in this answer are valid cmd.exe (batch-file) solutions that rely only on a call  to an external executable that ships with Windows (including .NET Framework), even in the no longer supported Windows 7, and as far back as the long-obsolete v2 of PowerShell (which Windows 7 originally came with, but since SP1 even the latest and last Windows PowerShell version, v5.1, was supported).

I need it to be .cmd script because it is elevating to admin, modifying configuration file and creating a service. I didn't use a single .ps1 script in my whole life, but everything is normal about using powershell inside .cmd, if it will work. For me what is provided is not working at all.

@VerityFreedom, code in comments in generally hard to read, especially without formatting. Please try my solutions as posted, in isolation (I just double-checked that they work), then gradually add in in your code.

@mklement0 I think I make it work someway but I need more testing for myself, thank you, if you have any additions how to make it work better then I'll wait. I created a different .cmd and it worked, it didn't work inside the initial .cmd script which is pretty long.

@mklement0 I got DataDirectory "C:\Users\Р В Р’В Р вЂ™Р’В­Р В Р’В Р вЂ™Р’В»Р В Р Р‹Р В Р вЂ°Р В Р’В Р СћРІР‚ВР В Р’В Р вЂ™Р’В°Р В Р Р‹Р В РІР‚С™\Desktop\MyFolder\data" instead of utf8NoBom Cyrillic (as in win 11 -Encoding Default), and everytime I run it it changes further and further.

@VerityFreedom, there is no such thing as utf8NoBom Cyrillic; by definition, UTF-8 is a Unicode encoding, i.e. a global alphabet, so to speak, that isn't specific to any one culture / language, and encompasses them all. Also note that Windows PowerShell  misinterprets BOM-less UTF-8 files by default, so if you want to inspect the resulting file, use Get-Content -Encoding utf8. It is for this reason that running the code repeatedly corrupts the file.  Are you really looking for BOM-less UTF-8 or are you looking for an encoding based on an  ANSI code page such as Windows-1251?

Let's review your actions here, @AmigoJack: You created a distraction by objecting to the answer based on a false dichotomy ("that's not CMD, it's just calling PS").
You suggested a distinctly inferior approach ("Why not calling [sic] PHP or straight an EXE all along?").
You created a distraction by incorrectly claiming that Windows PowerShell and/or .NET Framework couldn't be assumed to be present.
You used incendiary language ("Ugh, this is ridiculous").
When your arguments were refuted, you went silent and let your unhelpful / cantankerous comments stand.

@mklement0 when I use encoding default in win 11 the cyrillic symbols are becoming ?????? symbols in notepad, but the program reads them correctly, unlike in ascii. When I use encoding utf8 the cyrillic symbols are displayed as a proper cyrillic but the program can't read them. I read that encoding default in win 11 is utf 8 nobom and encoding utf8 is utf8bom. Am I missing something again? I'm not a really smart person. I probably need to check the formating of encoding -default in my win11 maybe thats not a utf8 nobom. I just need the formating in which my program will read cyrillic properly.

So if the target program reads your file correctly, it sounds like -Encoding Default is the solution - irrespective of what Notepad shows. BOM-less UTF-8 is only the default in PowerShell (Core) 7, whereas Windows PowerShell uses varying default encodings, depending on the specific cmdlet used, but some, such as Get-Content and Set-Content, default to the active ANSI code page, which you can query with ([System.Text.Encoding]::Default).WebName in Windows PowerShell. There is no default encoding at the OS level

@mklement0 I have a Tor Portable github repo with 130 stars used mainly by Russians, there is a service file creation, that is for now completely broken for cyrillic, it can't even start if your username is in cyrillic. I firstly added the chcp 1251 at the beginning of a program for a batch section, but it wasn't enough for the powershell section, so this is why I asked this question. It replaces paths in powershell here and there, to use absolute instead of relative in config file. I f thought my default is utf8nobom but now I don't know, and I'm not sure what is people defaults.

@VerityFreedom, if you execute chcp 1251 before calling powershell.exe, Windows PowerShell's Get-Content and Set-Content will use Windows-1252 by  default (which in the case of Get-Content means that it is used in the absence of a BOM), and -Encoding Default can be used to refer to it explicitly.

@mklement0 I also checked that my cmd is using Powershell 5 version despite being on win 11, so it cant use UTF-8 nobom by default, that means that using chcp 1251 and then -Encoding Default will use it for everyone if I understood it right. I hope so at least. Thank you very much it was very helpful!

Glad to hear it, @VerityFreedom. As of Windows 11, it is only Windows PowerShell (whose latest and last version is v5.1) that ships with the OS (whereas PowerShell (Core) 7 must be installed on demand), and it uses the system's active ANSI code page by default when reading BOM-less files, and, with Set-Content also when writing files (whereas Out-File / > default to UTF-16LE) - but external programs may default to different encodings.

Thus, @VerityFreedom, I'm not sure what the ultimate resolution is in your case, but, given that this answer addresses your question as asked,  note that you can help future readers by clearly signaling that fact - if applicable -  by accepting it.

I went silent because comments are not for excessive chats. You forcibly mixed PS and CMD into one thing, but they aren't - that's not (false) dichotomy, that's altering the scenario. If debug would be available (not in Win7x64 anymore) one would really stay in CMD's shell. I've encountered highscore accounts before that were oblivious about the crucial mis-distinction they made, not seeing how their answer misses the problem's environment. Not telling versions and using error handling now led to all this - I could have avoided this.

@AmigoJack, that's no excuse for leaving unhelpful comments behind, and no excuse for lack of accountability. Your imagining of a pure cmd.exe solution has nothing to do with the question, as evidenced by both the original question and the OP's responses since.

@mklement0 of course you helped me both in answer and in the comments I accept it fully.

@mklement0 unfortunately I can't accept two answers at the same time, but because of the second answer and additional tests for now I know that 1) My program doesn't work in UTF-BOM at all, and works in bomless utf8 in latin alphabet. But it doesn't work in bomless utf8 in cyrillic. 2) It works only in chcp 1251, which also corrupts cyrillic for the windows notebook only visually, but the program starts normally. It was the head pain for me not so long ago but now its fascinating.

*windows notepad

"unhelpful" - well, next time I'm gonna edit you right away, but I have the slight idea that you don't see that as help either. You're simply not able to take criticism (which is the help). I came for the Q title and was disappointed that a solution was redirected to PS. And it wasn't even that reliable - it was just quick (and dirty, given all the disadvantages I already named).

@AmigoJack: I see nothing that needs or needed editing and note that using edits to editorialize would amount to an abuse of the edit privilege.
Insisting that someone take criticism in the abstract is a logical fallacy as well as a (by definition inappropriate) ad hominem:
Your criticisms have been refuted; if you see a flaw in the refutations, address those.

Another way, skipping the first 3 bytes of the BOM. You need the double quotes to escape the pipe symbols from cmd. Use the same filename if you wish.
powershell "(get-content myfile.txt -Encoding Byte) | select -skip 3 | set-content myfile2.txt -Encoding Byte"

Here's a test you can run first that sets the errorlevel:
powershell "'239 187 191' -eq (get-content myfile.txt -Encoding Byte -totalcount 3)" | findstr True


This is a true accepted answer, my lord and savior. The first accepted answer was useful but not like this.

For some reason it didn't unblock cyrillic for me unlike chcp 1251 but the program started to work at least in a latin directory (before it wasn't).

Well I can't accept two answers at the same time unfortunately but for now I know that


My program doesn't work in UTF-BOM at all, and works in bomless utf8 in latin alphabet. But it doesn't work in bomless utf8 in cyrillic.


It works only in chcp 1251, which also corrupts cyrillic for the windows notebook only visually, but the program starts normally. It was the head pain for me not so long ago but for now its fascinating.



*Sorry, I meant windows notepad, not notebook.

@VerityFreedom You should take the [tour] to see how this website works. If you prefer a different answer as the better one you can un-accept your previous choice. And next time edit your question to append details.

Beware though that this does not check the file for actually having a 3-byte UTF-8 BOM, so if you happen to use this on a file in a different encoding you will most probably end up with an unreadable file..

@VerityFreedom, note that that this answer's solution is functionally equivalent (but slower, due to byte-by-byte processing) to the first solution in my answer -
assuming that the premise of your question holds (a with-BOM UTF-8 file that you want to convert to a BOM-less UTF-8 file).
If the input file doesn't have a UTF-8 BOM, the byte-based solution in this answer will corrupt your file, and the text-based approach in my solution may or
may not still work, depending on whether Get-Content detects or assumes the true encoding.

@VerityFreedom: If the rewritten file should use a different encoding - it sounds like you want Windows-1251 - a text-based approach is a must.
I've amended my answer to show how to transcode your file to Windows-1251 (Cyrillic).

Just for completeness, I have decided to add a batch file answer which does not use powershell.exe.
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "UTF8_BOM=%~1"
If Not Defined UTF8_BOM GoTo :EOF
If Not Exist "%UTF8_BOM%" GoTo :EOF

Set "_CodePage="
For /F "Tokens=*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com') Do For %%H In (%%G) Do Set "_CodePage=%%~nH"
If %_CodePage% NEq 65001 Call :CodepageChange 65001
Call :RemoveBOM "%UTF8_BOM%"
If Defined _CodePage (If %_CodePage% NEq 65001 Call :CodepageChange %_CodePage%)
Pause
Exit /B

:CodepageChange
%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com %1 1>NUL
GoTo :EOF

:RemoveBOM
Copy "%~1" "%TEMP%\_$.tmp" 2>NUL || GoTo :EOF
(Type "%TEMP%\_$.tmp" | ((Pause & Pause & Pause) 1>NUL & %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe "^")) 1>"%~1"
If Not ErrorLevel 1 Del "%TEMP%\_$.tmp"
GoTo :EOF

Just drag and drop your file, (represented in your question as MyFile.txt in the current working directory), onto the batch file. Alternatively the UTF-8_BOM file can be passed as an argument to the script via the command line interface.
